# R code that applies a function to subsection of variables of a dataframe and saves it to original dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe like mtcars

I want to program a function that searches for all variables of mtcars that start with "c", converts them to character and saves them back to mtcars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
f <- function(x, str = "^var") {
    want <- grep(str, names(x))
    x[, want] <- sapply(x[, want], as.character)
    x
}
```

[Edit: alternative version that implements the points raised by @hadley in comments.]

```
f <- function(x, str = "^var") {
    want <- grepl(str, names(x))
    x[, want] <- lapply(x[, want], as.character)
    x
}
```

The function allows you to pass through the string you want to match on, but defaults to `"^var"` as you requested. The `"^"` indicates we want to find names that start with `"var"`, not any name that contains `"var"`.

Example:

```
> bigdf <- data.frame(var1 = LETTERS[1:3], var2 = letters[1:3], var3 = 1:3, 
+                     stuff = 4:6)
> bigdf
  var1 var2 var3 stuff
1    A    a    1     4
2    B    b    2     5
3    C    c    3     6
> 
> bigdf2 <- f(bigdf)
> bigdf2
  var1 var2 var3 stuff
1    A    a    1     4
2    B    b    2     5
3    C    c    3     6
> str(bigdf2)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ var1 : chr  "A" "B" "C"
 $ var2 : chr  "a" "b" "c"
 $ var3 : chr  "1" "2" "3"
 $ stuff: int  4 5 6
```

Comment: doesnt work. results in: Error in df[, want] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: well it works for me. The issue might be an unfortunate choice of name for the argument `df` as that is a function - the error you quote is because somewhere you tried to subset the function `df`. I've altered the function to have a non-clashing argument name but I don't think that will solve the problem. Did you do *exactly* what I showed above?

Comment: You're generally better off using `grepl` instead of `grep`.  And you should probably use `lapply` instead of `sapply` - it won't make a difference here, but it's a bit more general.

Comment: @[Gavin Simpson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/429846/gavin-simpson) Thanks so much for solving this mysterious error I was also getting! `Error in df[, ...] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` is due to inadvertently trying to subset the (obscure) function `stats::df()`. **Lesson learned: never use `df` as the argname for a dataframe in a function**

Answer (score 2):

Another variation that illustrates another features of grep and another version the "[" operator:

```
f <- function(x, str = "^var") {
    want <- grep(str, names(x), value=TRUE)
    x[want] <- lapply(x[want], as.character)
    x
}
```

The value=TRUE argument returns the matching names rather than their position. You don't really need to use `[ , want]` and can instead just use `[want]`since this is a full column-wise operation. Checked to see that it (and Simpson's versions) returns the full data.frame even if no columns match. Please don't "accept" this answer  ... it's not much more than a comment, but it's really hard to read function structure in the comments.